# How to specify timezone to date filter

Tags: angularjs

I have this date: `1386800070703`. Let's say it's UTC.
How can I tell angular what timezone it is and in what timezone I want it displayed?

I'm currently using tihs which only converts it without any timezone info:
`{{1386800070703 | date:'d MMMM yyyy'}}`

And would like to be able to show a timezone to the right of the date.

Answer (score 11):

In the next version of AngularJS (1.3.0) you can specify the timezone this way:

```
{{someDate | date:'d MMMM yyyy Z' : 'UTC'}}
```

Currently, only supports UTC, as you can see in the docs: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/docs/api/ng/filter/date

You can play with it here: [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/AocWAjd46LHJAXvTZ1U1?p=preview)

Notice, the time zone will be shown as local-time even if specified otherwise.

Comment: why do it, and then only support UTC? wat.

Comment: Since version ```1.4.0-rc.0``` AngularJS supports other timezones too. For example to get Japan Standard Time you can use following: ```{{someDate | date: 'MMM d, y H:mm:ss Z' : '+0900'}}```

Comment: Sadly this additional timezone parameter is not supported in [Angular 2's Date pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-class.html).  Doing something like what is suggested in [the accepted answer for this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21785593/1392763) will still work in Angular 2.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a directive I wrote that does just that:

```
angular.module('CommonDirectives', []).directive('adjustTimezone', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      adjustTimezone: '@'
    },
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
      var date = new Date(attrs.adjustTimezone);

      date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
      element.text($filter('date')(date, attrs.filter));
    }
  }
}]);
```

Here's how you use it:

```
<span data-adjust-timezone="{{date.MilitaryTime}}" data-filter="EEEE, MMMM d, y h:mm a"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the element **Z**

```
'Z': 4 digit (+sign) representation of the timezone offset (-1200-+1200)

{{1386800070703 | date:'d MMMM yyyy Z'}}
```

Comment: Hm, that will only print out the machine's timezone offset. What I need is for that date to be coverted to the machine's timezone. I'll probably have to write my own filter for that, right?