# Using AngularJS date filter with UTC date

Tags: angularjs, datetime, angularjs-filter

I have an UTC date in milliseconds which I am passing to Angular's date filter for human formatting.

```
{{someDate | date:'d MMMM yyyy'}}
```

Awesome, except `someDate` is in UTC and the date filter considers it to be in local time.

How can I tell Angular that `someDate` is UTC?

Thank you.

Comment: *date* filter converts it to local time automatically.

Comment: It doesn't know that the date is UTC so the conversion is wrong.

Comment: @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470139/angularjs-timestamp-to-formatted-utc-time-with-date-helper

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: date filter adds timezone, how to output UTC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782893/angular-date-filter-adds-timezone-how-to-output-utc)

Comment: {{someDate | date:'d MMMM yyyy' : 'UTC'}}

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Similar Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782893/angular-date-filter-adds-timezone-how-to-output-utc/21785453#21785453)

I'll repost my response and propose a merge:

Output UTC seems to be the subject of some confusion -- people seem to gravitate toward [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Borrowing from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc#answer-6777470), you could do something like this (i.e. use a convert function that creates the date with the UTC constructor) without moment.js:

**controller**

```
var app1 = angular.module('app1',[]);

app1.controller('ctrl',['$scope',function($scope){

  var toUTCDate = function(date){
    var _utc = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),  date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
    return _utc;
  };

  var millisToUTCDate = function(millis){
    return toUTCDate(new Date(millis));
  };

    $scope.toUTCDate = toUTCDate;
    $scope.millisToUTCDate = millisToUTCDate;

  }]);
```

**template**

```
<html ng-app="app1">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.12" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
      <div>
      utc {{millisToUTCDate(1400167800) | date:'dd-M-yyyy H:mm'}}
      </div>
      <div>
      local {{1400167800 | date:'dd-M-yyyy H:mm'}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

here's [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eLwnLZReCy8HXtJyO84q?p=preview) to play with it

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662140/using-angularjs-date-filter-with-utc-date?lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470139/angularjs-timestamp-to-formatted-utc-time-with-date-helper).

Also note that with this method, if you use the 'Z' from Angular's date filter, it seems it will still print your local timezone offset.

Answer (score 114):

Seems like AngularJS folks are working on it in version 1.3.0.
All you need to do is adding `: 'UTC'` after the format string. Something like:

```
{{someDate | date:'d MMMM yyyy' : 'UTC'}}
```

As you can see in the [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/docs/api/ng/filter/date), you can also play with it here:
[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/AocWAjd46LHJAXvTZ1U1?p=preview)

BTW, I think there is a bug with the Z parameter, since it still show local timezone even with 'UTC'.

Comment: I think what the PO wants is to format a UTC date to a local format string, just the opposite.

Comment: Sadly this additional timezone parameter is not supported in [Angular 2's Date pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-class.html).  Doing something like what is suggested in the first answer will still work in Angular 2.

Comment: Hi @nir This works for me. question: any way I can get the Month names in Spanish instaed of English as it gives in above. so instaed of the month names like January, February, March...etc I need to make those as: enero, febrero, marzo? Any pointers would help.

Comment: If you want to convert value 1506508005197 to 09-27-2010 then use above suggested method by nir

{{record.deactivateDate | date:'MM-dd-yyyy' : 'UTC'}}

Comment: Whatever or not it answers the question, this is what I was looking for and works perfectly. But maybe for others: If you want to have it the other way around you just have to make sure your back-end is sending it as 2018-07-17T21:26:00.000+00:00. Angular then knows it is an UTC time and will convert it correctly to local time by default.

Comment: {{ data.publishedDate | date: 'mediumDate':'UTC' }}

Answer (score 11):

Here is a [filter](https://gist.github.com/cmmartin/341b017194bac09ffa1a) that will take a date string OR javascript Date() object. It uses [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and can apply any [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) transform function, such as the popular 'fromNow'

```
angular.module('myModule').filter('moment', function () {
  return function (input, momentFn /*, param1, param2, ...param n */) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2),
        momentObj = moment(input);
    return momentObj[momentFn].apply(momentObj, args);
  };
});
```

So...

```
{{ anyDateObjectOrString | moment: 'format': 'MMM DD, YYYY' }}
```

would display **Nov 11, 2014**

```
{{ anyDateObjectOrString | moment: 'fromNow' }}
```

would display **10 minutes ago**

If you need to call multiple moment functions, you can chain them. This converts to UTC and then formats...

```
{{ someDate | moment: 'utc' | moment: 'format': 'MMM DD, YYYY' }}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug filed against this in angular.js repo
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6546#issuecomment-36721868

Answer (score 4):

*An evolved version of **ossek** solution*

Custom filter is more appropriate, then you can use it anywhere in the project

**js** file

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.filter('utcdate', ['$filter','$locale', function($filter, $locale){

    return function (input, format) {
        if (!angular.isDefined(format)) {
            format = $locale['DATETIME_FORMATS']['medium'];
        }

        var date = new Date(input);
        var d = new Date()
        var _utc = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),  date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
        return $filter('date')(_utc, format)
    };

 }]);
```

in **template**

```
<p>This will convert UTC time to local time<p>
<span>{{dateTimeInUTC | utcdate :'MMM d, y h:mm:ss a'}}</span>
```

Comment: this is actually wrong because it no longer uses date's UTC functions - contrary to ossek's script. it would work though, if the date in `input` included the string " UTC" at the end.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It seems original answer has been updated after my reply :) I just wrapped his function in to a filter.

Comment: while we are at it: might i suggest using `$locale['DATETIME_FORMATS']['medium']` instead of the fixed fallback format? that way you use angular's own localization. Your format looks awfully like the en_US format, that is very uncommon everywhere else in the world

Comment: done! :). Template section leaved intact to show that can use to override the default formatting.

Answer (score 3):

If you do use moment.js you would use the moment().utc() function to convert a moment object to UTC. You can also handle a nice format inside the controller instead of the view by using the moment().format() function. For example:

```
moment(myDate).utc().format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: He doesn't want converting it to UTC, since it is already in UTC time. You should use it like this:
`moment().utc(myDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')`

Answer (score 2):

After some research I was able to find a good solution for converting UTC to local time, have a a look at the fiddle. Hope it help

https://jsfiddle.net/way2ajay19/2kramzng/20/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{date | date:'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' }}
</div>


<script>
function MyCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.d = "2017-07-21 19:47:00";
  $scope.d = $scope.d.replace(" ", 'T') + 'Z';
  $scope.date = new Date($scope.d);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have also the possibility to write a custom filter for your date, that display it in UTC format. Note that I used [`toUTCString()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toutcstring.asp).

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('dateCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.today = new Date();
});
    
app.filter('utcDate', function() {
    return function(input) {
       return input.toUTCString();
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
  
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dateCtrl">      
    Today is {{today | utcDate}}       
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it work declaring the filter the following way?

```
   app.filter('dateUTC', function ($filter) {

       return function (input, format) {
           if (!angular.isDefined(format)) {
               format = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
           }

           var date = new Date(input);

           return $filter('date')(date.toISOString().slice(0, 23), format);

       };
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are working in .Net then adding following in web.config inside

```
<system.web>
```

will solve your issue:

```
<globalization culture="auto:en-US" uiCulture="auto:en-US" />
```