# Date format in Angularjs in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.NET MVC project and I am trying to format date (dd/MM/yyyy) in my cshtml UI but its returning null.

Below is my cshtml code:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                        <td>{{item.Id}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.Manufacturer}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.BatchNo}}</td>
                        <td width="50px">{{item.ExpiryDate| date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
    </tr>
```

I tried two ways:

1) formatting in .NET cshtml itself but nothings happening:

```
<td width="50px">{{item.ExpiryDate| date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
```

2) I tried using filter but its returning null:

```
medApp.filter('cmdate', [
    '$filter', function ($filter) {
        return function (input) {
            return $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
        };
    }
]);
```

code in cshtml:

```
<td width="50px">{{item.ExpiryDate| cmdate: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
```

Any clue about the issue?

Thanks

Comment: show the `item.ExpiryDate` value

Comment: Is `ExpiryDate` a date **object**?

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka ... Its null when I use the custom filter. If I use {{item.ExpiryDate| date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} then its /Date(1513881000000)/  I am getting the values from SQL Server and its coming fine.

Comment: @Liam ...Its a field in product object.

Comment: Yes, obviously... your other comment says it is a date object

Comment: From your comments, you have [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Comment: Open the Network tab of the browser to see what are the values returned from the server.

Comment: @mihkov In the network tab it shows the same date format /Date(1513881000000)/ but in .NET controller the format is as retrieved from db.

Comment: @RameshRajendran I am looking into the url you specified. Thanks.

Comment: Guys, this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957878/convert-c-sharp-datetime-to-angular-date  The solution by @Vijaykumar vp ... but is it the right thing to do?

Comment: I suggest you to use the solution provided from @StephenMuecke . Else you can modify the models returned from the controller. For example: adding an additional property where the date is better formatted

Comment: Going ahead with the link and answered by Nitish Kumar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392328/how-to-format-date-in-angularjs  This one is similar to what @mihkov suggested.

Answer (score 0):

your date passing as json format. create the custom filter like this.

```
app.filter("cmdate", function() {
    var re = /\/Date\(([0-9]*)\)\//;
    return function(x) {
        var m = x.match(re);
        if( m ) return new Date(parseInt(m[1]));
        else return null;
    };
});
```

Now call it like this

```
<td width="50px">{{item.ExpiryDate| cmdate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
```

Comment: It would be better to fix the serialization at source so that all dates and times are serialized according to ISO8601. So much easier to deal with.

Comment: I tried using this but its the same.