# Showing wrong date conversion in angular v1.1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was having time="2015-06-26T18:50:07.000Z" as I am using angularv1.1 ,I can not use UTC and I dont have milliseconds as well,
What I have is only this time string

In HTML

```
<div ng-app='myapp' ng-controller="myctrl">
{{date | date:"MM/dd/yyyy" }}
</div>
```

In Controller

```
var x="2015-06-26T18:50:07.000Z"
var app=angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('myctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.date=x;
});
```

Where I want output as 06/26/2015 and it is showing 06/27/2015 may be  problem of GMT or UTC whatever .

Please suggest me ,What can I do to show 06/26/2015

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/obv10wd9/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using AngularJS date filter with UTC date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662140/using-angularjs-date-filter-with-utc-date)

Comment: That was not i actually want ..My problem is may similar to this but that is something which is not helping me out

Comment: Your time is in UTC. If you want to show it as it is, then the duplicate will show how. Otherwise you'll have to change the input to include your timezone.

Comment: my angular is v1.1 in which i can not provide timezone with it

Comment: [o rly?](http://jsfiddle.net/obv10wd9/3/)

Comment: Can you please provide me some solution I have added fiddle .

Comment: To which timezone the  date is given  "2015-06-26T18:50:07.000Z"   belongs or it is randomly generated?

Comment: Randomly genrated may be because it is generated by google script ,I dont to know timezone..

Comment: The Z at the end means it's UTC. Which in turn means that the [duplicate's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662140/using-angularjs-date-filter-with-utc-date) will work here too.

Comment: I have opened that solution may time but what i want to say to you is ,I failded to get what there answers  are.. Please update my fiddle if you know how this can be done.. while I will also try do it with that duplicate answer

Comment: I have copy-pasted the function from the duplicate to you fiddle and it works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/obv10wd9/7/

Comment: thanks @Juhana all I was doing was not converting into date object

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one.

You can do like this.

```
var x="2015-06-26T18:50:07.000Z"
var app=angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('myctrl',function($scope){
    var date=new Date(x);  
    $scope.date = new Date(date.getTime() +(date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000));

    console.log(typeof $scope.date)    
});
```

Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/obv10wd9/8/)