# input type="date" giving previous day date in HTML5

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm using below code for date.

```
<input type="date" value="{{data.endDate | date: "MM/dd/yyyy"}}" ng-model="data.endDate" />
```

If i select today date (11/22/2015) in the controller the endDate value is `2015-11-21T18:30:00.000Z`.

1. How can i get exact selected date value?
2. The model date is not displaying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using AngularJS date filter with UTC date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662140/using-angularjs-date-filter-with-utc-date)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because, the date object for the selected date is created and is represented according to UTC standards.

**Solution**

1. You will have to do a bit of **temporal calculations** in order to get the expected **date** value. Refer [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329/) to understand the actual working to reach the desired goal.
2. The simplest way, ones the date has been selected from the date picker, **"convert the date object to a string** using Date's *locale convention method*,      **dateObject.toLocaleDateString()**. Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) for further understanding.

example :  $scope.dateOfTransactionFilter.toLocaleDateString()

Hope this helps.
Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Thanks nishi bangar,

The simplest way, ones the date has been selected from the date picker, "convert the date object to a string using Date's locale convention method, dateObject.toLocaleDateString(). Refer this for further understanding.