# angularjs convert Date to UTC format in controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to convert below date and time to UTC format

```
"1970-05-11T18:30:00.000+0000"
```

I am able to do this inside view, but i want to do it in the controller.

```
{{stmt.tranDate | date:"dd/MM/yyyy": 'UTC'}}
```

### controller

```
$scope.kycinfo.dob = "1970-05-11T18:30:00.000+0000";
$scope.dob = $filter('date')($scope.kycinfo.dob, "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

### view

```
<input type="text" id="dateOfBirth" placeholder="Please Select ..."  data-ng-model="dob" name="dob" ng-required="true" mobi-date=true />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using AngularJS date filter with UTC date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662140/using-angularjs-date-filter-with-utc-date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass "UTC" as third parameter to $filter('date).

```
$scope.kycinfo.dob = "1970-05-11T18:30:00.000+0000";
$scope.dob = $filter('date')($scope.kycinfo.dob, "dd/MM/yyyy", "UTC");
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try the following code:

```
 var toUTCDate = function(date){
    var _utc = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),  date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
    return _utc;
  };
```

you can also visit [Using AngularJS date filter with UTC date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662140/using-angularjs-date-filter-with-utc-date)