# Transform a timestamp into date format inside AngularJS interpolation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, interpolation

Having a timestamp, for example `1519357500`, is it possible to send it in this form to html and convert it into date format inside interpolation?

I've tried to do it like this but it doesn't work:

```
{{moment($ctrl.myTimestamp).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}}
```

Comment: @barbsan unfortunately the same result, nothing showed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using AngularJS date filter with UTC date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662140/using-angularjs-date-filter-with-utc-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, very easily.

```
{{$ctrl.myTimestamp | date:'MMMM d y, h:mm:ss a'}}
```

(this assumes $ctrl.myTimestamp contains the epoch milliseconds)

If you have the seconds till epoch do this:

```
{{$ctrl.myTimestamp * 1000 | date:'MMMM d y, h:mm:ss a'}}
```

More information [here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: this is perfect! but I don't know why it doesn't show the year and it shows `YYYY` instead :D

Comment: @dadsa might depend on the version, try just `Y`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, now it shows that single `Y`. you're talking about AngularJS version? it's 1.6

Comment: @dadsa typo, just `y` *

Comment: @dadsa you can check this link for more info about the syntax: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: yeah, now it shows the year but I realized that the result is not correct. my timestamp is 1519357500 which should be **February 23, 2018 3:45** but the result is **January 18, 1970 4:02**. do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Yes, you have the seconds till epoch. The above method only works for the milliseconds till epoch. Multiplying your seconds by a 1000 should fix that. I'll update the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it.

ps. I am just doing it using no dependency (`moment`). coz I've never used it. So this is how you can achieve this.

```js
var app = angular.module('test-app', []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){

$scope.timestamp = "1519357500";
var date = new Date($scope.timestamp * 1000);
var datevalues = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + date.getFullYear() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes();
$scope.timestamp = datevalues;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test-app" ng-controller="testCtrl">
 {{timestamp}}
</div>
```